# Normalized cut: what does this code do?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm going through some [MATLAB code for Normalized Cut for image segmentation](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jshi/software/), and I can't figure out what this code below does:

```
% degrees and regularization
d = sum(abs(W),2);
dr = 0.5 * (d - sum(W,2));
d = d + offset * 2;
dr = dr + offset;
W = W + spdiags(dr,0,n,n);
```

`offset` is defined to be 0.5.

`W` is a square, sparse, symmetric matrix (`w_ij` is defined by the similarity between pixels `i` and `j`).
`W` is then used to solve the eigenvalue problem `d^(-1/2)(D-W)d^(-1/2) x = \lambda x`

The `w_ij`'s are all positives because of the way the weights are defined, so `dr` is a vector of 0's.

What are the offsets for? How are they chosen? What's the reason behind `offset*2`? I have the feeling this is to avoid some potential pitfalls in certain cases. What could these be?

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you post a link to the NCuts code you refer to?

Comment: @Shai [here](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jshi/software/) you go -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you came across a piece of code written by [Prof Stella X Yu](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~stellayu/).
Indeed, when `W` is positive this code has no effect and this is the usual case for NCuts.
However, in a [CVPR 2001 paper](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/stellayu/doc/cvpr01.pdf) Yu and Shi extend NCuts to handle **negative** interactions as well as positive ones. In these circumstances `dr` (r for "repulsion") plays a significant role.

Speaking of negative weights, I must say that personally I do not agree with the approach of Yu and Shi.
I strongly believe that when there is repulsion information [Correlation Clustering](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~bagon/pub/LargeScaleCorrClust_2011.pdf) is a far better objective function than the extended NCuts objective. Results of some image segmentation experiments I conducted with negative weights suggested that Correlation clustering objective is better than the extended NCuts.

Comment: @user2121792 you are most welcome. if you come across negative affinities - let me know, I have a soft spot for them :)